# How to generate signed APK in android studio hedgehog

Tags: android-studio

I an unable to find build option from main menu, can someone help me in generating signed APK.
The following is the new ui of android studio. Thanks in advance...[image]

Answer (score 1):

The option is hidden inside the main menu, click on the option that I indicate in red and you can find the menu to generate the apk, I hope it helps.Click on the image in the link below for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE15W.png)